# iPhone alarm without vibration?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have using an iPhone 5 upgraded to iOS 7. Is it possible to turn off vibrations for alarms? I am currently using a song as alarm sound, the vibration is annoying.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem so.

A workaround would be to turn off vibrations when on silent (Settings > Sounds), and have it set to silent (either by the button or a Do Not Disturb).

Maybe another app would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Close... in Sound options you can set it to vibrate or not when tone... phone calls and alarms.
When "silent" it will be sound alarm and vibration, but in "tone" it will have sound but no vibration.
The only thing is that you can miss calls if you don't hear it cause it will no longer vibrate, just sound (loudy place)... but in silent there will be vibration and no sound.

Answer (score 0):

Leave all your settings as is. Leave it on ring at night. Swipe up from the bottom of the screen to open Control Center and then activate **Do Not Disturb**.

Comment: This will not stop the alarm from sounding or vibrating.

Answer (score -1):

For jailbroken phones, you can use [NoVibratedWakeup](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=novibratedwakeupDp).